# Le couplet de la chanson « On se ressemble »

Tags: sens, figure-de-style

Je m’enquiers à vous du commencement d’une chanson que je ne comprends pas. Les chanteurs ouvrent la chanson *On se ressemble* de *Les vieilles valises* par les phrases ci-dessous.

> Voici l'histoire d'un pauv' ringard
>
> Qui à force d'errer dans les bars
>
> Se fait larguer par une bombe
>
> Et faut qu'ce soit sur moi, qu'elle tombe..!

Voici la première chose qui me surprenait : La chanson décrit un « pauvre ringard », mais selon le Wiktionnaire, ni *pauvre* ni *ringard* peuvent être utilisés comme nom commun, ce qui dénue la première ligne de sens. Moi, je pense à un homme affligé avec des vieilles coutumes, ça vous semble juste ?

Ceci est la deuxième chose ce qui me paraît étrange : La personne se fait larguer « par une bombe ». Pour autant que je sache, *larguer* peut désigner deux choses :
« Larguer une bombe », c’est jeter une bombe d’un avion.
« Larguer quelqu’un » veut dire rompre une liaison amoureuse avec quelqu’un de façon attristante et un peu grossière
Ici, je pense que « la bombe » est une femme, bien que ça se frotte à la pensée que c’est plutôt pour trouver une amie que l’on erre dans des bistrots que pour la perdre. (Mes propos sous-entendent qu’*à force de* exprime un but, un dessein. Je ne m’en suis pas mépris ?)

Cette « bombe » est le sujet de la dernière ligne. Il semble que c’est elle qui tombe malgré que ce soit le « pauvre ringard » qui a été largué. Peut-être je me doute à tort de voir un lien entre *tomber* et *larguer*. Pourtant, même si *tomber sur* ne veut dire que *rencontrer*, la dernière ligne semble contredire tout ce qui la devance.

Est-ce que le parolier joue avec des mots ici, et qu’est-ce qu’il veut exprimer comme ça ? Et s’il n’y a pas de calembours dans ce morceau de la chanson, comment est-ce que vous l’expliquerez sans tenir compte de ces jeux de mots apparents ?

Comment: À http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/ringard il y a deux acceptions pour *ringard* comme nom commun.

Comment: M’enfin! Comment est-ce que cette acception m’est échappée ? Je pensais avoir lu la page dont vous me donnez le lien avec soin.

Answer (score 9):

L'auteur s'amuse à combiner des termes à sens multiples.

L'usage d'un adjectif pour désigner une personne qui présente cette caractéristique est extrêmement commune en français. On dit ainsi *un barbu* pour *un type barbu*. Rien d’exceptionnel à la première ligne, donc. Autant le Robert que [le TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ringard) cite l'usage nominal de l'adjectif, qu'ils définissent "Personne incapable, médiocre."

Dans la 3e ligne, *bombe* est un usage informel voire argotique. C'est une femme particulièrement belle et sexy (comme dans l'anglais *bombshell*). Il est ici magnifiquement combiné avec *larguer* au sens d'"abandonner", mais dont le sens littéral militaire est plutôt "lâcher [qqc] sur une cible".

Finalement, *c'est sur moi que ça tombe* signifie "c'est à moi que ça arrive".

Essentiellement, l'auteur dit qu'une fille, qui s'est séparée d'un incapable, se retrouve en sa compagnie (soit que c'est sa nouvelle petite amie, ou tout simplement qu'elle lui raconte ses déboires etc.). La formulation suggère qu'elle lui cause d'ailleurs des problèmes. Il enveloppe le tout avec brio dans une [métaphore filée](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A9taphore_fil%C3%A9e) autour de l'idée d'une bombe.